# use an image as icon in ipyvuetify

Tags: python, vuetify.js, ipywidgets, voila

I am using ipyvuetify to code an app to be rendered with voila and I would like to use an image as icon for footer (or in the future for a button). Any idea how to do it?

This is the code for an icon

```
v.Footer( absolute = False,
          class_="font-weight-medium",
          children= [v.Col(class_="text-center", cols="12", children=[v.Icon(children=['fingerprint']),'BMW - 2020 - alpha version 0.0. powered by Soft company PPP'])]
```

this will generate:
[image]

I want to use my own logo instead of the predefined fingerprint.
So how can I load an image and give a relative size to the font.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there seems to be no good way to simply pass relative link to ipyvuetify and have it display the image (if there).

A workaround I found is to open the file with ipywidgets and pass this to ipyvuetify as object:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
file = open( 'LINK_TO_YOUR_ICON', 'rb')
image = file.read()
img = widgets.Image(value=image, format='png')

v.Footer( absolute = False,
          class_="font-weight-medium",
          children= [v.Col(class_="text-center", cols="12", children=[img,'BMW - 2020 - alpha version 0.0. powered by Soft company PPP'])]
        )
```

check if this solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

With a few modifications to Christoph Weiss-Schabers answer it can be done with ipyvuetify:

```
import base64
import ipyvuetify as v

file = open( 'LINK_TO_YOUR_ICON', 'rb')
image = file.read()
image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image).decode('ascii')
img = v.Img(src=f'data:image/png;base64,{image_base64}')

v.Footer( absolute = False,
          class_="font-weight-medium",
          children= [v.Col(class_="text-center", cols="12", children=[img,'BMW - 2020 - alpha version 0.0. powered by Soft company PPP'])]
        )
```

Or for an online image:

```py
v.Img(src='https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png', width='100', height='100')
```